# Adding trigger to a column in Mysql using migration file in Cakephp-3

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I am using migration file to change database. I can creating and updating DB using migration. But I don't know how to make a trigger using migration code in Cakephp-3. I have a sample code of mysql code and want the Cakephp-3 migration code like the raw mysql code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `uid` BEFORE INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW SET new.uuid = REPLACE(UUID(),"-","");
```

Comment: Normally ORM migration code only support basic ANSI SQL standard statements like CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX, ALTER, INSERT, and UPDATE.. i never worked with CakePHP before but maybe it's possible to connect to the database ( https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#executing-queries ) and execute a raw SQL query ( https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#creating-connections-at-runtime ) within a migration

Comment: You can very simply use `$this->execute('YOUR SQL HERE');` inside your Phinx migration.

Comment: Thanks  Greg Schmidt for your suggestion. I am using  `$this->execute('YOUR SQL HERE');` But here have to use the Mysql code. I want to use Cakephp code like: 
`$table->addColumn('deposit_amount', 'float', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => true,
            'precision' => 15,
            'scale' => 2,
        ]);`